# How to check type of Vue component at runtime?

Tags: vue.js

I have a component `tab-panel` and a component `tab`, and need to ensure that `tabs` are only rendered if inside of a `tab-panel`.

How do I check the type of the parent to enforce this?

Comment: I believe you can check with `this.$parent.constructor.options.name`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the name of the parent component via `this.$parent.$options.name`.

Here's and example:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.component('tab', {
  template: `<div>tab</div>`,
  created() {
    if (this.$parent.$options.name !== 'tab-panel') {
      throw new Error('tab must be in tab-panel!')
    } else {
      console.log('tab is in tab-panel :)')
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('tab-panel', {
  template: `<div>tab-panel<tab></tab></div>`,
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <tab-panel></tab-panel>
  <tab></tab>
</div>
```